UIMenu from button inside TablviewCell Not showing properly
I am displaying menu from button as follow:
final class YourCustomCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    private let menuButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton()
        button.showsMenuAsPrimaryAction = true
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return button
    }()
    
    override class func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        
        self.contentView.addSubview(menuButton)
        configureButtonConstraints()
        configureMenu()
    }
    
    private func configureButtonConstraints() {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            menuButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor),
            menuButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor),
            menuButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor),
            menuButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor)
        ])
    }

    private func configureMenu() {
        let editAction = UIAction(title: "Edit") { _ in
            print("Edit Button Clicked")
        }
        
        let deleteAction = UIAction(title: "Delete") { _ in
            print("Delete Button Clicked")
        }
        
        let menuForCell = UIMenu(title: "Options", options: UIMenu.Options.displayInline, children: [editAction, deleteAction])
        menuButton.menu = menuForCell
    }
}

It works fine to display menu, but after display of 1 second
menu is moved to the top of screen and not showing beside the button.
How can I solve this?
Thank you,

Hi, it is working fine for me as per your code, https://prnt.sc/baIwKB4rmQ2H

In your code  override class func awakeFromNib()  from this remove class.

I got my mistake!
